# Using Ruby, how can I convert a string to an array when there may be variable whitespace between terms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

Imagine I have a string like this: `"hello:world, foo:bar,biz:baz,    last:term  "`

And I want to convert it to an array `["hello:world", "foo:bar", "biz:baz", "last:term"]`

Essentially I want to split by comma, but also by a variable amount of whitespace. I could do the split and then go through each term and strip whitespace from either side, but I'm hoping there is a simpler way - maybe using Regexp? (I'm very unfamiliar with how to use Regexp). I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scan` with a Regexp:

```
string = "hello:world, foo:bar,biz:baz,    last:term  "
string.scan(/[^\s,]+/)
#=> ["hello:world", "foo:bar", "biz:baz", "last:term"]
```

Or you could use `split` to split the string at the `,` and the `strip` to remove the unwanted whitespace.

```
string = "hello:world, foo:bar,biz:baz,    last:term  "
string.split(',').map(&:strip)
#=> ["hello:world", "foo:bar", "biz:baz", "last:term"]
```

I would probably prefer the second version because it is easier to read and understand. Additionally, I wouldn't be surprised if the simple string methods of the second version would perform better for small strings because Regexps are pretty expensive and usually only worth it for more complex or bigger tasks.

Comment: Or `string.strip.split(/\s*,\s*/)`

Comment: `string.delete(" ").split` comes to mind